# Closing Android application for some amount of time

Tags: java, android

I need to have a button which goes to home screen (so my app must disappear), then allows a user to do something, and after some time of doing nothing (e.g. 30 sec) my app should be displayed again automatically. How am I able to do it?

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 1):

On pressing the button, do two things:

- Dismiss all `Activity`s of the current task
- Start a `Service`

From this `Service`, you can start your app's `Activity` by calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, someActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

after a fixed time, say 15 seconds or so. Use a `Timer` inside the `Service` for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want to do is to display my app again not after a fixed time, but after phone being idle for fixed time e.g. user clicks some apps, does whatever he wants, then he goes away, and from now after 30sec I want to display my app again. Is it doable?